# Permission denied to access property "textContent" (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I'm trying to fix an old automated test script for work. I'm new to programming and I have got this far:

```
# Check if I can play some game
Then(/^I should be able to play (.+)$/) do |game_name|
  # TODO: better check for game play, game end, score count

  if page.has_content?("GUEST")
    find(:css, ".play", :text => "Play").click
  else
    start_game(game_name)
  end
 #Here is where the error pops up: 
  if page.has_content?('Writing')
    # Dont wait for players to join
    expect(page.has_content?('Waiting for players')).to eq(true)
  else
    # Check for game object
    page.should have_css("object#game")

    # Check if correct game loading
    current_url.should match(/#{GameWorld::GAMES[game_name]}/)
  end

  #Quick escape
  ensure_on?('city')
end
```

Could someone give me a hint of how to fix the issue?

The error that I get is:

```
`Error: Permission denied to access property "textContent" (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError)` .
```

If more information is needed let me know.

Any way to improve would be great. Also, I accept all suggestions on ways to automate a sanity test.

Comment: Please add the stack trace you're getting with that error and the versions of Capybara, selenium-webdriver and Firefox you are using

Comment: I use the latest Firefox - 45.7.0. Also, the gem versions are: capybara (2.12.0, 2.11.0) and selenium-webdriver (3.0.5, 3.0.3).

Comment: Did my answer solve the issue ? (you selected it as answered but then added the gem versions) - If not add the full error message with stacktrace.

Comment: I will have to check it out tomorrow when I'm at work. Will let you know. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what versions you're using it's tough to say exactly what is the causing the error you're getting, but I would guess that upgrading to the latest version of Capybara will probably fix that error.  Beyond that there are a few things in your test that need improving.

1. The `has_xxx?` methods have a waiting behavior built-in which is useful when you expect the thing they check for to occur 95+% of the time, but if it's more like 50/50 then your test is slower than it needs to be.
2. Never use expectations against the result of the `has_xxx?` methods, instead just use the `have_xxx` matcher since the error messages will be more descriptive and useful when there are failures
3. You should never use `current_url`/`current_path` with the `eq`/`match` matchers, instead you should use the have_current_path matcher.  This will make your tests more stable due to the retrying behavior built-in to it.
4. Don't mix expect and should syntax, it leads to hard to read/understand tests.

Putting that all together, you test should be more like

```
# Check if I can play some game
Then(/^I should be able to play (.+)$/) do |game_name|
  # TODO: better check for game play, game end, score count

  expect(page).to have_content(game_name) # This should be something that is on the page for both GUEST and logged in users just to verify the page has loaded
  if page.has_content?("GUEST", wait: false)  #disable the waiting/retrying behavior since we now know the page is already loaded
    find(:css, ".play", :text => "Play").click
  else
    start_game(game_name)
  end

  expect(page).to have_content('Something') # Same as above - check for something that will be on the page when the actions triggered by the `click` or `start_game` calls above have finished

  if page.has_content?('Writing', wait: false) #disable waiting because previous line has assured page is loaded
    # Dont wait for players to join
    expect(page).to have_content('Waiting for players')
  else
    # Check for game object
    expect(page).to have_css("object#game")

    # Check if correct game loading
    expect(page).to have_current_path(/#{GameWorld::GAMES[game_name]}/)
  end

  #Quick escape
  ensure_on?('city')
end
```

Comment: Thanks, will try it out. Thank you for your help!